# Big numbers in lambdify

Tags: numpy, sympy, lambdify

I have (automatically generated by SymPy) expression, including sqrt function with big numbers under sqrt and small multiplier  in front of it. So overall result must be within float range, but value under sqrt - is not. I coonvert this expression to Python function using lambdify command. Call of this function gets exception:

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols("t")
k = 10
f = 2 * 10 ** (- k) * sqrt(10 ** (2 * k) * t ** 2 + 1)
print(f)
F = lambdify(t, f)
t0 = 10 ** 10
T = np.arange(t0, 2 * t0, t0 / 4)
print(T)
F(T)
```

Output:

```
2.0e-10*sqrt(100000000000000000000*t**2 + 1)
[1.00e+10 1.25e+10 1.50e+10 1.75e+10]
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15740/1035914544.py in <module>
      8 T = np.arange(t0, 2 * t0, t0 / 4)
      9 print(T)
---> 10 F(T)

<lambdifygenerated-11> in _lambdifygenerated(t)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(t):
----> 2     return 2.0e-10*sqrt(100000000000000000000*t**2 + 1)

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable sqrt method
```

For `k = 2` code works properly:

```
0.02*sqrt(10000*t**2 + 1)
[1.00e+10 1.25e+10 1.50e+10 1.75e+10]
array([2.0e+10, 2.5e+10, 3.0e+10, 3.5e+10])
```

Is there any way to fix this problem without manually rewriting expression?

UPD: Looks like it is a problem of NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
k = 10
def F1(t):
    return np.sqrt( (10 ** (- k)) ** 2 * 10 ** (2 * k) * t ** 2 + 1)
def F2(t):
    return 10 ** (- k) * np.sqrt(10 ** (2 * k) * t ** 2 + 1)
print(F1(10 ** 5))
print(F2(10 ** 5))
```

First call works, second call - not!

Comment: Default `lambdify` code uses `numpy`. Thus the sqrt is `np.sqrt` which good for float arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Converting argument of np.sqrt to numpy.double solves problem:

```
def Sqrt(x):
  return np.sqrt(np.double(x))
F = lambdify(t, f, {'sqrt': Sqrt})
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the large multiplier, the `np.sqrt` argument is object dtype array:

```
In [3]: 100000000000000000000 * T**2
Out[3]: array([1e+40, 1.5625e+40, 2.25e+40, 3.0625e+40], dtype=object)
```

With object dtype arrays, `numpy` iterates (at list comprehension speed), applying a 'method' to each element.  In effect

```
 1e+40.sqrt() etc
```

Hence the `no method error`.

Your fix:

```
In [3]: np.double(100000000000000000000 * T**2)
Out[3]: array([1.0000e+40, 1.5625e+40, 2.2500e+40, 3.0625e+40])

In [4]: np.sqrt(_)
Out[4]: array([1.00e+20, 1.25e+20, 1.50e+20, 1.75e+20])
```

or

```
In [6]: np.sqrt((100000000000000000000 * T**2).astype(float))
Out[6]: array([1.00e+20, 1.25e+20, 1.50e+20, 1.75e+20])
```

Comment: The question is how to fix this problem universally? We have expression (function) with large numbers inside it and want to apply it to numpy array without manually editing code of this function.