# Evaluation and plot of Sympy expression at discrete points

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I need to plot a function given by a fairly large expression:

```
x = sym.symbols('x')
myExpression          # This is a sympy.core.mul.Mul object
```

[image]

The function shall be evaluated at several locations, say `xx`.

```
xx = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
npFunction = sym.lambdify(x, myExpression, 'numpy')    # Returns a numpy-ready function
yy = npFunction(xx)                                    # npFunction evaluated at xx

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-125-c1419d5b446d> in <module>
>       3 npFunction = sym.lambdify(x, myExpression, 'numpy')    # Returns a numpy-ready function
>       4 
> ----> 5 yy = npFunction(xx)                  # npFunction evaluated at xx
> 
> <lambdifygenerated-289> in _lambdifygenerated(x)
>       1 def _lambdifygenerated(x):
> ----> 2     return (-sqrt((320725082215391709755025*x**33 - 815422810503339070188975*x**32 - 1193164908737087748974400*x**31 +
> 18560901327587253919468800*x**30 + 512047920200188971110400*x**29 -
> 127260011757049326412185600*x**28 + 306772243802105606125977600*x**27
> + 1070548851848211221210726400*x**26 - 1961736173650180102867124224*x**25 -
> 2043216442426554791067910144*x**24 +
> 20778411631353349207247290368*x**23 +
> 16419727423460480613177360384*x**22 -
> 66868981841519012898775498752*x**21 +
> 67300051166011139997189537792*x**20 +
> 501457285381778570989390528512*x**19 +
> 58984656008435300127576424448*x**18 -
> 770564128787015129334013755392*x**17 +
> 2383958940411190086665689366528*x**16 +
> 6680747916713488973675806851072*x**15 +
> 503828111007578114462098391040*x**14 -
> 2034404207870885321852376317952*x**13 +
> 30465381943482129786499667853312*x**12 +
> 59161051678387568374654370316288*x**11 +
> 22656488686277206871130236780544*x**10 +
> 25867916241733015054414793146368*x**9 +
> 197755683253795159275985170333696*x**8 +
> 342754876018815970343942545735680*x**7 +
> 243094537594392980163602530959360*x**6 +
> 205865801906815623280028886761472*x**5 +
> 569403883326394857936120214192128*x**4 +
> 951945434951209699659257330270208*x**3 +
> 826990214251602314720389336399872*x**2 +
> 375422648073841563687008008667136*x +
> 72196663091123377632116924743680)/(320725082215391709755025*x**32 -
> 1136147892718730779944000*x**31 - 57017016018356969030400*x**30 +
> 18617918343605610888499200*x**29 - 18105870423405421917388800*x**28 -
> 109154141333643904494796800*x**27 + 415926385135749510620774400*x**26
> + 650043217739693276371353600*x**25 - 2599613121056318867661389824*x**24 + 562394515222247038758420480*x**23
> + 20025142331250461800019263488*x**22 - 3571036809095361690970619904*x**21 -
> 62317425686762007867684814848*x**20 +
> 127057289683979840164347248640*x**19 +
> 367603862071831402168945999872*x**18 -
> 297587003931102575412494991360*x**17 -
> 465179510051631596016974692352*x**16 +
> 2752388157125925508448274874368*x**15 +
> 3849951183506387395294443601920*x**14 -
> 3149101257277365518368833011712*x**13 +
> 920748397656278579501516980224*x**12 +
> 28188364693143617825236787920896*x**11 +
> 30335736114672592269485361070080*x**10 -
> 6638321976039230113499383332864*x**9 +
> 29451390533998320848280584454144*x**8 +
> 158594220779076065717198788755456*x**7 +
> 178182786085519359475770250493952*x**6 +
> 64903893188814670694539396644864*x**5 +
> 128047726690656602860146049155072*x**4 +
> 409455196193065444920428750438400*x**3 +
> 514739646382493706461483636883456*x**2 +
> 303225984982718186054891083923456*x +
> 72196663091123377632116924743680)))
> 
> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float
> which has no callable sqrt method
```

However, I am obtaining the error above. I wonder whether this is caused by numerical difficulties?
This piece of code is inside a loop, and `myExpression` gets incrementally larger every cycle. For the first few cycles the procedure above works fine.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with Numpy and the huge integer numbers.

Comment: Interesting: the following works. `[npFunction(t) for t in xx]`

Comment: Davide_sd your approach solved my problem. As you and @hpaulj pointed out, this may very well be an issue with Numpy handling large integers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler expr involving `sqrt` and powers of `x`, `lambdify` works

```
In [46]: expr = sqrt(x**2 + x**3 + 4)

In [47]: f = lambdify(x, expr, 'numpy')

In [48]: f(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2))
Out[48]: 
array([[2.        , 2.44948974],
       [4.        , 6.32455532]])
```

The error tells me that your expression has something more going on, beyond what I can see in your image or the error.   The argument to `np.sqrt` is apparently an object dtype array.  `sqrt` on an object dtype array tries to do `element.sqrt()` for each element, resulting in your error.

You might try taking the `sqrt` out of the expression, and seeing what sort of array you get.  The large integer values could very well be producing the error.  Python `int` can be arbitrarily large, but `numpy` ints are restricted to `int64` size.

With just one of your terms:

```
In [16]: def foo(x):
    ...:    return (16419727423460480613177360384*x**22)
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [17]: foo(2)
Out[17]: 68869328411129987677772255368052736

In [18]: foo(np.arange(-2,3))
Out[18]: 
array([68869328411129987677772255368052736, 16419727423460480613177360384,
       0, 16419727423460480613177360384,
       68869328411129987677772255368052736], dtype=object)
```

Note the the `object` dtype.

`np.sqrt(Out[18])` raises this error

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type int 
   which has no callable sqrt method
```

Similar question a month ago

[Big numbers in lambdify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71232932/big-numbers-in-lambdify)